# Possibility of Split brain in ActiveMQ Artemis HA shared storage?

Tags: activemq-artemis

What are the possibilities of split brain in Artemis HA shared storage deployment? ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 is deployed as HA active/passive with shared storage in AWS EFS. Any specific log statements to check in `artemis.log`?

master cluster configuration

```xml
    <connectors>
       <connector name="artemis">tcp://<master_ip>:61616</connector>
       <connector name="discovery-connector">tcp://<slave_ip>:61616</connector>
    </connectors>
    
    <cluster-connections>
       <cluster-connection name="artemis_cluster_configuration">
          <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
          <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                
          <max-hops>1</max-hops>
          <static-connectors>   
             <connector-ref>discovery-connector</connector-ref> 
          </static-connectors> 
       </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>
    
    
    <ha-policy>
       <shared-store>
          <master>
             <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
          </master>
       </shared-store>
    </ha-policy>
```

slave cluster configuration

```xml
    <connectors>
       <connector name="artemis">tcp://<slave_ip>:61616</connector>
       <connector name="discovery-connector">tcp://<master_ip>:61616</connector>
    </connectors>
    
    <cluster-connections>
       <cluster-connection name="artemis_cluster_configuration">
          <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
          <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
          <max-hops>1</max-hops>
          <static-connectors>   
             <connector-ref>discovery-connector</connector-ref> 
          </static-connectors> 
       </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>
    
    
    <ha-policy>
       <shared-store>
          <slave>
             <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
             <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
          </slave>
       </shared-store>
    </ha-policy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, shared storage is resilient against split-brain. I believe the only issue related to shared storage and split-brain which has been fixed since 2.17.0 is [ARTEMIS-4143](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4143) which deals with the primary broker becoming disconnected from the shared storage and then reconnecting after the backup has already become active.

If you are using a `discovery-group` in your `broker.xml` then if you encounter split-brain you'll likely see a `WARN` log message with a code of `AMQ212034` that says:

```
There are more than one servers on the network broadcasting the same node id. You will see this message exactly once (per node) if a node is restarted, in which case it can be safely ignored. But if it is logged continuously it means you really do have more than one node on the same network active concurrently with the same node id. This could occur if you have a backup node active at the same time as its live node. nodeID={}
```

That said, I'm not certain about the locking semantics of AWS EFS. ActiveMQ Artemis shared storage was designed to run on a SAN or NAS filesystem that supports exclusive file locks (e.g. NFSv4). If AWS EFS supports that then it should be fine. Otherwise it won't work properly and both brokers are likely to be active simultaneously (i.e. encounter split-brain).

Comment: Edited the question with configuration. we use `static-connectors` in broker.xml.  Noticed in Jira ARTEMIS-4143, mentioned issue resolved in `2.29.0`. We are still using Java 1.8, so we can upgrade to `2.19.1`. Any additional suggestion in configuration? Error code `AMQ212034` still same with `static-connectors` ?

Comment: I *strongly* encourage you to upgrade from Java 8 to at least 11. The latest LTS is 17 which was released almost 2 years ago now. There have been _13_ releases of ActiveMQ Artemis since 2.19.1 which include hundreds of bug fixes and many new features.

Comment: I don't have any additional configuration suggestions at this point.

Comment: The `AMQ212034` log message _only_ appears if you've using a `discovery-group`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. Technically any issue if we upgrade Artemis deployment in JDK 11 and rest of application clients in JDK 1.8?

Comment: You need to ask a _new_ question about upgrading JDK on clients & server.